# Adding functions breaks embedded C code (no IDE)

Tags: c, arm, embedded, qemu

I've been trying to get into embedded C programming...the very bare-metal, only toolchain, not IDE. For that I've been writing my own linker script as well. The issue is that when there are any other functions except `main` inside my C code, the `PC` and `SP` (program counter and stack pointer registers) are messed up.

I'll provide the code:

Linker:

```
ENTRY(start)

MEMORY {
  FLASH (rw)  : ORIGIN = 0x0000000000000000, LENGTH = 0x000000000000BFFF
  RAM (rwx)   : ORIGIN = 0x0000000040000000, LENGTH = 0x000000001FFFFFFF
}

_estack = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);

SECTIONS {
  .text : {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)
  } > FLASH

  .data : {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;
    *(.data)
    *(.data*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;
  } > RAM AT> FLASH

  .bss : {
    _sbss = .;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;
  } > RAM
}
```

ASM file (I'll add more stuff later):

```
.syntax unified
.cpu cortex-a8

.global start

.word _estack

.word _sbss
.word _ebss

.word _sdata
.word _edata

.section .text
start:
  ldr sp, =_estack

  b main
```

Also compile flags are:

```
CFLAGS := -c \
    -g
    -march=armv7-a \
    -nostdlib

QEMU_FLAGS := -m $(MEMORY) \
    -S \
    -machine cubieboard \
    -cpu cortex-a8  \
    -gdb tcp::$(PORT)
```

**Problem demonstration:**

C Code:

```c
int main(void) {

    volatile int a = 0, b = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i < 4; i++) {
        int k = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = k;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

GDB (set architecture to "arm") output:

```
start () at start.s:16
16        ldr sp, =_estack
(gdb) load
Loading section .text, size 0x94 lma 0x0
Start address 0x00000088, load size 148
Transfer rate: 1184 bits in <1 sec, 148 bytes/write.
(gdb) info reg
...
sp             0x0                 0x0 <main>
lr             0x0                 0
pc             0x88                0x88 <start>
cpsr           0x400001d3          1073742291
fpscr          0x0                 0
fpsid          0x410330c0          1090728128
...
Quit
(gdb) step
start () at start.s:18
18        b main
(gdb) step
main () at main.c:1
1       int main(void) {
(gdb) step
3               volatile int a = 0, b = 1;
(gdb) info reg
...
r11            0x5ffffffb          1610612731
r12            0x0                 0
sp             0x5fffffe7          0x5fffffe7
lr             0x0                 0
pc             0xc                 0xc <main+12>
cpsr           0x400001d3          1073742291
fpscr          0x0                 0
fpsid          0x410330c0          1090728128
...
```

ie. all good.

When I have functions:

C code:

```
void my_func(void) {
    int volatile c = 1000;
}

int main(void) {

    volatile int a = 0, b = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i < 4; i++) {
        int k = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = k;
    }

    my_func();

    return 0;
}
```

GDB Output:

```
start () at start.s:16
16        ldr sp, =_estack
(gdb) load
Loading section .text, size 0xbc lma 0x0
Start address 0x000000b0, load size 188
Transfer rate: 1504 bits in <1 sec, 188 bytes/write.
(gdb) step
start () at start.s:18
18        b main
(gdb) step
main () at main.c:5
5       int main(void) {
(gdb) step
my_func () at main.c:3
3       }
(gdb) print a
No symbol "a" in current context.
(gdb) info regs
Undefined info command: "regs".  Try "help info".
(gdb) info reg
...
sp             0x0                 0x0 <my_func>
lr             0x2c                44
pc             0x14                0x14 <my_func+20>
cpsr           0x400001d7          1073742295
...
(gdb) disas my_func
Dump of assembler code for function my_func:
   0x00000000 <+0>:     push    {r11}           @ (str r11, [sp, #-4]!)
   0x00000004 <+4>:     add     r11, sp, #0
   0x00000008 <+8>:     sub     sp, sp, #12
   0x0000000c <+12>:    mov     r3, #1000       @ 0x3e8
   0x00000010 <+16>:    str     r3, [r11, #-8]
=> 0x00000014 <+20>:    nop                     @ (mov r0, r0)
   0x00000018 <+24>:    add     sp, r11, #0
   0x0000001c <+28>:    pop     {r11}           @ (ldr r11, [sp], #4)
   0x00000020 <+32>:    bx      lr
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00000024 <+0>:     push    {r11, lr}
   0x00000028 <+4>:     add     r11, sp, #4
   0x0000002c <+8>:     sub     sp, sp, #16
   0x00000030 <+12>:    mov     r3, #0
   0x00000034 <+16>:    str     r3, [r11, #-16]
   0x00000038 <+20>:    mov     r3, #1
   0x0000003c <+24>:    str     r3, [r11, #-20] @ 0xffffffec
   0x00000040 <+28>:    mov     r3, #2
   0x00000044 <+32>:    str     r3, [r11, #-8]
   0x00000048 <+36>:    b       0x78 <main+84>
   0x0000004c <+40>:    ldr     r2, [r11, #-16]
   0x00000050 <+44>:    ldr     r3, [r11, #-20] @ 0xffffffec
   0x00000054 <+48>:    add     r3, r2, r3
   0x00000058 <+52>:    str     r3, [r11, #-12]
   0x0000005c <+56>:    ldr     r3, [r11, #-20] @ 0xffffffec
   0x00000060 <+60>:    str     r3, [r11, #-16]
   0x00000064 <+64>:    ldr     r3, [r11, #-12]
   0x00000068 <+68>:    str     r3, [r11, #-20] @ 0xffffffec
   0x0000006c <+72>:    ldr     r3, [r11, #-8]
   0x00000070 <+76>:    add     r3, r3, #1
   0x00000074 <+80>:    str     r3, [r11, #-8]
   0x00000078 <+84>:    ldr     r3, [r11, #-8]
   0x0000007c <+88>:    cmp     r3, #3
   0x00000080 <+92>:    ble     0x4c <main+40>
   0x00000084 <+96>:    bl      0x0 <my_func>
   0x00000088 <+100>:   mov     r3, #0
   0x0000008c <+104>:   mov     r0, r3
   0x00000090 <+108>:   sub     sp, r11, #4
   0x00000094 <+112>:   pop     {r11, lr}
   0x00000098 <+116>:   bx      lr

(gdb) print &c
$1 = (volatile int *) 0xfffffff8
```

0xfffffff8 extends beyond the RAM as written on linker skript.

Can someone please explain what is going wrong and how I prevent it?

Comment: BTW, Is this Fibonaci  order (still trying to analyse...) so stack grows downward?

Comment: @DraženGrašovec Yes, I've provided `_estack` (end of stack) to the stack pointer in my asm. Works properly without functions, but when functions come into picture, it just just behaves weirdly.

Comment: If your SP value is 0x5fffffe7 then something has gone wrong -- SP must be at least 4 aligned, and for the usual C procedure calling standard must be 8 aligned on function entry. You have the RAM and FLASH lengths wrong -- they should be a nice round multiple of something.

Comment: @PeterMaydell yes, fixing the length sizes did it. Can you please tell me why an incorrect allignment caused this issue?

Comment: Architecturally, the low 2 bits of the SP register for Thumb are defined as SBZP (should be zero, preserve the value) -- if you write a non-zero value to them this is UNPREDICTABLE and pretty much anything could happen. The exact details of what happened would depend on what QEMU's internal implementation happens to do, what the compiler emits. Basically, you broke your end of the contract with the hardware and with the C compiler :-)  Since you say this was the fix, I'll write up an answer.

Comment: PS: when using gdb and trying to debug stuff at the assembly level, the "stepi" command to step a single instruction can be more useful than "step" which tries to step a whole line of C code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wrong values for the RAM and FLASH lengths in your linker script. They should be a nice round multiple of something -- memory sizes in hardware are never odd numbers like that.

This mistake has resulted in your setting the initial SP value to 0x5fffffff. This is not permitted by the Arm Procedure Calling Standard, which says:

> SP mod 4 = 0. The stack must at all times be aligned to a word boundary.

and that at a public interface (i.e. when you call into a function compiled by the C compiler):

> SP mod 8 = 0. The stack must be double-word aligned.

(https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/main/aapcs32/aapcs32.rst)

If you break these rules then the behaviour is not defined, which is to say that anything in theory could happen. The exact specifics of what happens will depend on what code the C compiler has emitted.

In this case we can see that the compiler has emitted LDR and STR instructions to access memory in the stack. In the mode in which the CPU starts execution, those will take a Data Abort exception if you try to use them on an unaligned address. Exceptions on Arm are handled by the CPU starting execution at the appropriate entry point in low memory. Your program doesn't set up any code at the exception vectors, it just puts your startup routine there, so if an exception happens at any point execution will jump to partway through that startup routine.

I would suggest that you put a proper set of exception vectors at the start of your program, even if the code at each entry point is just "branch to same address", i.e. a tight loop. That way if you have a bug in your code then you'll see that you've taken an exception (because the CPU will start looping at one of the exception vector addresses), rather than having weird behaviour.

You should also probably have a look through the procedure calling standard, because it specifies all the things your code needs to have set up to be able to call a C function.

Answer (score 0):

First case seems odd too.

In 1st case compiler reserves 16 bytes on stack for variables a, b, i, k:

```
   0x00000024 <+0>:     push    {r11, lr}
   0x00000028 <+4>:     add     r11, sp, #4
   0x0000002c <+8>:     sub     sp, sp, #16
```

In `my_func` compiler reserves 12 bytes on stack for variable c:

```
   0x00000004 <+4>:     add     r11, sp, #0
   0x00000008 <+8>:     sub     sp, sp, #12
   0x0000000c <+12>:    mov     r3, #1000       @ 0x3e8
```

I cant get why 12 bytes is needed for c nor how it ends with 0.
What happens when you remove `volatile` qualifiers?

What GDB says of process map `i proc m`?
Could it be that it is some issue with emulator.

Comment: Removing volatile still gives weird memory for a & b.... b is `0xe52daff8`, and SP becomes `0xfffffff4`, and GDB command give `process 1 warning: unable to open /proc file '/proc/1/maps'`

Comment: It's 0x5fffffe7 because it started as 0x5fffffff, then we subtract 8 for the "push" of two registers, then we subtract 16 for the "sub sp, sp, #16". The 12 bytes in my_func is probably because the compiler is not optimising, so it is conservative about leaving space for things it might need to save but turns out not to. With optimisation turned on it doesn't do this kind of apparently unnecessary work.

Comment: Yes you are right, i missed "push".